# Is there a way to get a flying effect with a Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet map with a Mapbox geocoder.  With a map that is fully rendered by Mapbox, when you put a location into the geocoder the map has a "flying" effect from your current location to the new location.  Is there a way to get this effect on a Leaflet map.

I can't find anything in the Leaflet documentation (though there may be a search term for this effect that I just don't know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`flyToBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-flytobounds) method to sets the view of the map in Leaflet with a smooth animation.

For example, using `leaflet-control-geocoder`:

```
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
    defaultMarkGeocode: false,
    geocoder: new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim("")
}).addTo(map);

geocoder.on("markgeocode", function (e) {
    map.flyToBounds(L.polygon([
        e.geocode.bbox.getNorthWest(),
        e.geocode.bbox.getSouthWest(),
        e.geocode.bbox.getSouthEast(),
        e.geocode.bbox.getNorthEast()
    ]).getBounds());
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have bounds but just want to pan/zoom to a point, use `map.flyTo(myLatLng, myZoom)`